# How to count items that are nested inside a second level groupBy?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-collection

```
$bookings = Salon::find(3)->bookings;

$bookings->groupBy(['booking_status', function ($item) {
            return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item['created_at'])->format('Y-m');
}])->toArray();
```

This gives me below.

```
"confirmed" => [
       "2020-12" => [
         [],[],[],[]
        ]
];
```

However, I am looking for something like this below:

```
"confirmed" => [
       "2020-12" => 4
];
```

Comment: could do `groupBy(...)->map->count()` (the parentheses next to map are  omitted on purpose)

Comment: Where exactly though? My Tinkerwell throws errors every single time.

Comment: you already have `groupBy(...)->toArray()` this will make it `groupBy(...)->map->count()->toArray()`

Comment: I tried that: it gives me the following `[ "confirmed" => 2, "no_show" => 1, "canceled" => 1 ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have two levels of grouping and want to count things in the second level then you could do:

```
$bookings = Salon::find(3)->bookings;

$bookings->groupBy(['booking_status', function ($item) {
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item['created_at'])->format('Y-m');
}])->map(function ($dateGroup) {
   return $dateGroup->map->count();
})->toArray();
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I tried this before, I swear. The only thing I was missing was the `->map->`. Because I thought I didn't need it as I was already doing a map before. So the question arises, why the second map? It's 7am here so I am a bit numb.

Comment: When you group by with 2 levels you get a result which looks like e.g. `booking_status -> date -> [ elements of a booking status on a date ]` the first map will change the form of all elements of the booking_status and those are basically split into dates so the second map will change the form of elements within that date